# Why jQuery ui selectable plugin is disabling my original bound click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have problem with normal click when i attach `jquery.ui-selectable` to a row

jquery-ui-selectable is working fine as per desired but my attached click is not working

i have read somewhere to do

```
e.metaKey = false; //true i did both, but did not work
```

My code looks like this in jsfiddle

```
 $('#selectable').selectable({filter:'li'})

/* $('#selectable').bind("mousedown", function (e) {
           e.metaKey = true;
 }).selectable() */
 
 
 $('#selectable li').bind("click", function (e) {
    alert('clicked item : '+$(this).text());
});
```

**Question:** i want my attached `click` to work normally as we expect.

**here is demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/eabangalore/71xvp5ko/

I have similar code in my project where click is not working

**Note:** i want my answer to be working in jsfiddle, here in snippet it works don't know why, i my project it does not work

Comment: You want to display `text` when you click on the actual `li` item ?

Comment: yes, but it works in embeded snippet here, but does not work in my project as well in jsfiddle

Comment: Where is the embedded snippet - its the same code as js fiddle.

Comment: yes it is same code, but works without imaginary dotted lines, we call that feedback, i want it to work with imaginary dotted lines here too(code snippet)

Comment: Do you have the exact same code and bind method in your project as well ?

Comment: yes it is same way done, there imaginary dotted lines work, but click does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221775/discussion-between-always-helping-and-eab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want actual `click` function to then you need to add `pointer-events:none` to this class `ui-selectable-helper` so that click event is NOT `bubbling` up.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$('#selectable').selectable({
  filter: 'li',
})

$("#selectable > li").on('click',function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

#selectable li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}

.ui-selectable-helper {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

You can simply use [selected](https://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected) method of `jQuery selectable` plugin - there is **no** need to do additional `bind` or `click` functions to get the clicked item `li` text() as you wanted.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$('#selectable').selectable({
  filter: 'li',
  selected: function(event, ui) {
    var selectedLi = $(ui.selected).text()
    console.log(selectedLi); //clicked li item text
  }
})
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

#selectable li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: that's good , but i do have outside click handler code which is having different logic, i want it to work, `$('#selectable li').on('click',function(){//some logic})`  . my project manger won't allow me to change attached click handler

Comment: my project manager want attached click handler `$('#selectable li').on('click',function(){//some logic})` to work independently, only on click. he want jquery-ui selecatble for selection only